# Zooming and panning only work on first try using gesturelistener for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7.1, visual-studio-express

I’m new to windows phone development and trying to use the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit for zooming and panning on an image.  My issue is that zooming and panning only work on the first try.  If I zoom/pan on the image, go elsewhere within the app and then go back to the image it doesn’t do anything.  The OnPinchStarted method never runs when it is supposed to be envoked. I’ve used several different ways that I’ve found from searching here and elsewhere for the gesturelistener.  Code is posted below. Before I go another route and toss out this way I wanted to see if there is something I’m missing with what I have because it works just fine the first time.

First try:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Image x:Name="Map"
        Source="Images/park.png" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Stretch="Uniform" >
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener
                    PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted"
                    PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta"
                    DragDelta="OnDragDelta"/>
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform
                    ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"
                    TranslateX="0" TranslateY="0"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
// these two fields fully define the zoom state:
    private double TotalImageScale = 1d;
    private Point ImagePosition = new Point(0, 0);


    private const double MAX_IMAGE_ZOOM = 5;
    private Point _oldFinger1;
    private Point _oldFinger2;
    private double _oldScaleFactor;

    // Initializes the zooming operation
    private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        _oldFinger1 = e.GetPosition(Map, 0);
        _oldFinger2 = e.GetPosition(Map, 1);
        _oldScaleFactor = 1;
    }

    //Computes the scaling and translation to correctly zoom around your fingers.
    private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var scaleFactor = e.DistanceRatio / _oldScaleFactor;
        if (!IsScaleValid(scaleFactor))
            return;

        var currentFinger1 = e.GetPosition(Map, 0);
        var currentFinger2 = e.GetPosition(Map, 1);

        var translationDelta = GetTranslationDelta(
            currentFinger1,
            currentFinger2,
            _oldFinger1,
            _oldFinger2,
            ImagePosition,
            scaleFactor);

        _oldFinger1 = currentFinger1;
        _oldFinger2 = currentFinger2;
        _oldScaleFactor = e.DistanceRatio;

        UpdateImageScale(scaleFactor);
        UpdateImagePosition(translationDelta);
    }

    //Moves the image around following your finger.
    private void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var translationDelta = new Point(e.HorizontalChange, e.VerticalChange);

        if (IsDragValid(1, translationDelta))
            UpdateImagePosition(translationDelta);
    }

    //Computes the translation needed to keep the image centered between your fingers.

    private Point GetTranslationDelta(
        Point currentFinger1, Point currentFinger2,
        Point oldFinger1, Point oldFinger2,
        Point currentPosition, double scaleFactor)
    {
        var newPos1 = new Point(
         currentFinger1.X + (currentPosition.X - oldFinger1.X) * scaleFactor,
         currentFinger1.Y + (currentPosition.Y - oldFinger1.Y) * scaleFactor);

        var newPos2 = new Point(
         currentFinger2.X + (currentPosition.X - oldFinger2.X) * scaleFactor,
         currentFinger2.Y + (currentPosition.Y - oldFinger2.Y) * scaleFactor);

        var newPos = new Point(
            (newPos1.X + newPos2.X) / 2,
            (newPos1.Y + newPos2.Y) / 2);

        return new Point(
            newPos.X - currentPosition.X,
            newPos.Y - currentPosition.Y);
    }

    //Updates the scaling factor by multiplying the delta.
    private void UpdateImageScale(double scaleFactor)
    {
        TotalImageScale *= scaleFactor;
        ApplyScale();
    }

    //Applies the computed scale to the image control.
    private void ApplyScale()
    {
        ((CompositeTransform)Map.RenderTransform).ScaleX = TotalImageScale;
        ((CompositeTransform)Map.RenderTransform).ScaleY = TotalImageScale;
    }

    //Updates the image position by applying the delta.
    //Checks that the image does not leave empty space around its edges.
    private void UpdateImagePosition(Point delta)
    {
        var newPosition = new Point(ImagePosition.X + delta.X, ImagePosition.Y + delta.Y);

        if (newPosition.X > 0) newPosition.X = 0;
        if (newPosition.Y > 0) newPosition.Y = 0;

        if ((Map.ActualWidth * TotalImageScale) + newPosition.X < Map.ActualWidth)
            newPosition.X = Map.ActualWidth - (Map.ActualWidth * TotalImageScale);

        if ((Map.ActualHeight * TotalImageScale) + newPosition.Y < Map.ActualHeight)
            newPosition.Y = Map.ActualHeight - (Map.ActualHeight * TotalImageScale);

        ImagePosition = newPosition;

        ApplyPosition();
    }

    //Applies the computed position to the image control.
    private void ApplyPosition()
    {
        ((CompositeTransform)Map.RenderTransform).TranslateX = ImagePosition.X;
        ((CompositeTransform)Map.RenderTransform).TranslateY = ImagePosition.Y;
    }

    //Resets the zoom to its original scale and position
    private void ResetImagePosition()
    {
        TotalImageScale = 1;
        ImagePosition = new Point(0, 0);
        ApplyScale();
        ApplyPosition();
    }

    //Checks that dragging by the given amount won't result in empty space around the image
    private bool IsDragValid(double scaleDelta, Point translateDelta)
    {
        if (ImagePosition.X + translateDelta.X > 0 || ImagePosition.Y + translateDelta.Y > 0)
            return false;

        if ((Map.ActualWidth * TotalImageScale * scaleDelta) + (ImagePosition.X + translateDelta.X) < Map.ActualWidth)
            return false;

        if ((Map.ActualHeight * TotalImageScale * scaleDelta) + (ImagePosition.Y + translateDelta.Y) < Map.ActualHeight)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    //Tells if the scaling is inside the desired range
    private bool IsScaleValid(double scaleDelta)
    {
        return (TotalImageScale * scaleDelta >= 1) && (TotalImageScale * scaleDelta <= MAX_IMAGE_ZOOM);
    }
```

Second Try(from http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jprosise/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-4)

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta"
        PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" DragDelta="OnDragDelta" />
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="HambyTransform" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Image Source="Images/trails.png" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Stretch="Uniform" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
private double _cx, _cy;
private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        _cx = HambyTransform.ScaleX;
        _cy = HambyTransform.ScaleY;
    }

    //scale the map
    private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //compute the new scaling factors
        double cx = _cx * e.DistanceRatio;
        double cy = _cy * e.DistanceRatio;

        // If they're between 1.0 and 4.0, inclusive, apply them

        if (cx >= 1.0 && cx <= 4.0 && cy >= 1.0 && cy <= 4.0)
        {
            HambyTransform.ScaleX = cx;
            HambyTransform.ScaleY = cy;
        }
    }

    private void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        HambyTransform.TranslateX += e.HorizontalChange;
        HambyTransform.TranslateY += e.VerticalChange;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts to find a fix, which I never did, I started all over with a new project and the issue went away.  Zoom/pan works fine.  I don't know what happened or if something internal in my project was corrupt, but its working now.  I hope this helps anybody who runs into the same issue.  I had to do alot of copying/pasting code, but it worked.